# Java bean gets property name instead of value

Tags: java, spring, annotations, javabeans

I have a .properties file with bunch of properties in it. Here's an example:

```
mes.mail.debug=true
cookie.sso.domain = .stuffStuff.com
blabla.endpoint = blabla.com
test.value.property = myValue
```

The problem is with the last one (Which I have just added to the project we're working on).
I read the properties using `@Value("${PropertyName}")` annotation and it was working perfectly until lately, when I use the same thing, the variable gets the propertyName instead of its value:

```
@Value("${test.value.property}")
private String mProperty;
```

so, mProperty gets `"test.value.property"` where what I'm looking for is for it to get "myValue".

What's happening exactly? Is there something wrong with my project? I have tested in my friend's computer and it works perfectly.

By the way, i'm using `Spring Tool Suite`.

**EDIT:** It turns out that it doesn't detect the changes I make in the properties file. So if I change an old property's value; it acts as if nothing happened. 
Does anyone has any idea why it's doing like this?

Comment: Where do you use this annotation? Maybe you use it without  `@Component`?

Comment: Tried it. Same problem

Comment: What change lately on your local copy? Did you try to clean your target directory from eclipse/maven and re-run your app?

Comment: You don't have a `PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer` or `PropertiesPlaceholderConfigurer` set. If you have and it isn't working then there is too little information in this question to give a concrete answer.

Comment: I'm looking for the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

When you declare a Property Placeholder Configurer to load the properties files, you can set it to ignore unresolvable placeholders.

This means that if the property you are injecting with @Value is not found, its name (or key) will be assigned to the variable.

In your case, this option is enabled and the file that has been loaded by the application is not the one you are editing.

To see from where the file is been loaded, check the placeholder configurer location property.